# How to get value of custom element on click using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

This is my html

```
<a href="#" data-value="val1" id="catedit">Link1</a>
<a href="#" data-value="val2" id="catedit">Link2</a>
<a href="#" data-value="val3" id="catedit">Link4</a>
```

I want to get `data-value` of clicked `<a>` control where this have same id's.

I tried this code.But not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#catedit').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).data('value');
    alert(val);
  });
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qa86q7f8/3/)

Comment: You have an extra parenthesis after `'value'))` which is breaking your js

Comment: sorry,it was my typing mistake.

Comment: Yea, after you remove it, works for me as expected.

Comment: No,only the value of first link is showing.

Comment: That's because you're using the id instead of another selector. Use `$('a')` and it'll work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you have duplicated the same `id` attribute across multiple elements when they should be *unique*. As a result only the first element with that `id` is selected.

To fix this, use a common `class` attribute instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.catedit').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).data('value');
    console.log(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-value="val1" class="catedit">Link1</a>
<a href="#" data-value="val2" class="catedit">Link2</a>
<a href="#" data-value="val3" class="catedit">Link4</a>
```

Comment: Yeah,my controls have same id and it must be there.

Comment: That's invalid HTML. You need to remove them. The classes can be added regardless, though

Comment: Thanks for your effort.I finally got this solution , https://jsfiddle.net/qa86q7f8/3/

Comment: Given that that fiddle is clearly broken I don't see how that's a solution?

Comment: Check now  :-)  .

Comment: Now it's the same fiddle as in your question, which still does not work.

Comment: Fair enough, although be wary as that click handler will run for any `<a>` element on your page - not just those with the `data` attribute you're trying to target

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('[id="catedit"]')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id="catedit"]').click(function() {                   
    var val = $(this).data('value');
    alert(val);
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-value="val1" id="catedit">Link1</a>
<a href="#" data-value="val2" id="catedit">Link2</a>
<a href="#" data-value="val3" id="catedit">Link4</a>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qa86q7f8/3/)

Comment: Using `data()` is correct - and preferred in most instances. The issue is solely  due to the repeated `id`

Comment: have udpated my answer @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: This still won't solve the issue though unfortunately. Also given that 1.4.3 is over 7 years out of date, I'd be surprised if anyone had to use `attr()` over `data()` for compatibility reasons

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this will fix the issue

Comment: True, although it's a bit of a hack. The real issue is that the HTML is invalid.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yup but although it answers to his question

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#catedit').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert(val);
  });
});
```